# What's the meaning of "a stick called the truth"?

Tags: meaning

> EMMA:
>   I can't believe it. Mum have you seen this? To Nancy Burrows who pushed me to the next level with a stick called the truth.

What is the meaning of "with a stick called the truth"? Is it an idiom? If so, what is the meaning of that idiom? And when is it used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is certainly not a fixed expression.

The idea here is that someone got *pushed with a stick*. This can be meant in a literal way, but usually, as in this case, it is meant metaphorically.

The author combines the idiomatic ideas that he was *pushed to the next level* and that he was *pushed with a stick*. The combination *pushed to the next level with a stick* is a bit of a mix up, but readily understandable. It means that he reached the next level because someone encouraged or forced him, and it was done as if they pushed him with a stick, i.e. not in a very gentle way.

To explain in what way such a metaphorical stick was used, the author indicates that it was the truth that pushed him. (Supposedly, Nancy exposed something to him or about him that was a (painful) truth and because of that he eventually reached that next level.

*Naming* the metaphorical stick *the truth* indicates that this use of the truth was what made the *push* feel like it was done with *a stick*.

> Nancy Burroughs made me move to the next level.
>   It felt as if she pushed me.
>   It felt as if she pushed with a stick.
>   The stick she used was *the truth*.

Comment: I think there is also a nod to the use of a stick to beat someone, or as a "motivator" in use of stick and carrot (which is the same use of the stick really). So you are not metaphorically *pushed* by the stick itself, but by the unwritten use of metaphorical beating that the stick administers. In other words, "the truth" was used as a "weapon" to administer a metaphorical beating, which motivated the student to progress.

Comment: I would have liked to reward you with a carrot for this answer, but the best I could do is +1.